# While building an android Softkeyboard, detect change in cursor position when it is manually done by clicking on edittext

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

I trying to build a Softkeyboard for android and I want to detect changes in cursor position whenever it is manually done by clicking on the textfield.
Can you suggest how to go about it. My class extends InputMethodService and implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener.